# How to reset the base tag

Tags: php, html, curl, simple-html-dom, base-tag

So am using [simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) , i want to retrieve part of the page, that seems to work fine :) but the links are not correct , they are relative to my site...
on which i decided to use the base tag instead
....here is what i have

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = "http://bm.erciyes.edu.tr/";
$file = file_get_html($url);

echo "<base href='$url'>";
foreach($file->find('div.onemliduyurular') as $var){
    echo $var->innertext;
}


$url = "http://bm.erciyes.edu.tr/";
?>

<h1>Return to my Site</h1>
<?php

// I want this link here become relative to my site again
echo "<a href='hello.php'>Go This Way</a>";
```

so added this line above the foreach

```
echo "<base href='$url'>";
```

is there a way in which i can reset the base tag? or any other alternative ;)

inner text contains this

```
// get dom node's inner html
    function innertext()
    {
        if (isset($this->_[HDOM_INFO_INNER])) return $this->_[HDOM_INFO_INNER];
        if (isset($this->_[HDOM_INFO_TEXT])) return $this->dom->restore_noise($this->_[HDOM_INFO_TEXT]);

        $ret = '';
        foreach ($this->nodes as $n)
            $ret .= $n->outertext();
        return $ret;
    }
```

and this is the announcement am pulling [image]

Comment: Just use an absolute URL.

Comment: You need to modify those links to include full path, there should be something for that in simple-html-dom.

Comment: @SLaks cant use absolute path , thanks though ...

Comment: @enrey i have been looking for that for a while now , for some reason cant figure it out :(

Comment: what's in that `$var->innertext`?

Comment: i have added the innertext function @enrey

Comment: I mean what's the result of `$var->innertext` in your code... Write `var_dump($var->innertext);` in the loop instead of echo and post the result.

Comment: @enrey the vardump is a string with html tags of the annoucement am pulling

Comment: The edit has changed the question to something rather different. Please don’t do that. We want questions and answers to remain useful to future visitors.

Comment: @Fahad I know it's string with html tags, but what's in the string? Never mind, if there are links in those html tags, you need to change them to use absolute addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***One of the way is done by  using absolute url***

...
What if you prepend your url with the relative one that comes from the pulled site....
   As in

```
<?php
foreach($html->find('div.onemliduyurular') as $d) {
    foreach($d->find('a[href]') as $goAway){
        $goAway->href =$url.$goAway->href;
        }
    echo $d->innertext;
}
$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

**I hope it may work with your project**

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change the base address in another `base` element, since the HTML [syntax for `head`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#edef-HEAD) allows at most one `base` element. HTML5 does not change this; it explicitly [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-base-element): “If there are multiple base elements with href attributes, all but the first are ignored.”

The conclusion is that you need to emit appropriate absolute URLs.

Comment: is there a way without using the base tag ?

Comment: A way to do what? The original question was rather different from the current one. And I suppose we still haven’t seen the real problem. But in HTML, `base` is **the** way to set the base address.

Comment: @Fahad there is a way, you need to use absolute addresses.

Comment: @enrey , see i want to set the base tag multiple times , since the site that i am pulling infomation does not use absolute adresess  (it uses relative ones ) - trust me i want to use absolute adress... and am working on pulling info from many sites , so i need to change the base url multiple times :( in which the base tag can only be used once( "JukkaK.Korpela" 's answer )

Comment: @Fahad yes i know, you need to parse that html and complete those addresses, so you have absolute addresses. You have to get your hands dirty and dig into that bloody string and change it manually, that's what I'm saying. In php, there's http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php class that will help you with that. You will have to learn some Xpath and it's probably not going to be just few lines of code, deppends how much variety there is in the html.